# Always getting the same value if the checkbox is unchecked also

Tags: javascript, jquery

1. Input checkbox will be like this

```
    <input id="idCheckbox" name="check" type="checkbox" value="AllValue" style="width: auto; height: auto; font-weight: bolder;" data-bind="checked: idCheckbox" />
```

Always getting the same value (AllValue) if the checkbox is unchecked also.

```
   var AllPoliciesChk = document.getElementById("idCheckbox").value;
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("idCheckbox").checked`

Comment: Well of course - that is what the `value` attribute is - what are you expecting?

Comment: That's how checkboxes work. The value never changes, only the `checked` model property. What else would you expect ?

Comment: check whether the checkbox is checked or not? If it is checked, get the value, else don't. Always checkbox .value gives the same value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try it, its working fine for me. I have used jquery here is the working example in jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/26Ltymkx/

jquery code

```
 var AllPoliciesChk = document.getElementById("idCheckbox").value;

    $(document).on('click', '#idCheckbox', function(){
        if ($('#idCheckbox').is(":checked")) {
            //...your code
        }
      } 
    })
```